# Sharing token between MicroService and Monolithic applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

We have the microservice architecture and one monolithic application, in which we need to communicate from microservice to monolithic application API which requires the authentication.

Microservices are created with the hipster with the following architecture

- Jhipster Registry
- API Gateway
- UAA - Authentication service (Uses Oauth2)
- Microservice 1
- Microservice 2...n

Configurations for the authorization server are as follows

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class UaaConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
    /**
     * Access tokens will not expire any earlier than this.
     */
    private static final int MIN_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECS = 60;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @EnableResourceServer
    public static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private final TokenStore tokenStore;

        private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

        public ResourceServerConfiguration(TokenStore tokenStore, CorsFilter corsFilter) {
            this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
            this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/**",  "/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.GA)
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId("jhipster-uaa").tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }
    }

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private final UaaProperties uaaProperties;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UaaConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, UaaProperties uaaProperties, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
        this.uaaProperties = uaaProperties;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        int accessTokenValidity = uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getAccessTokenValidityInSeconds();
        accessTokenValidity = Math.max(accessTokenValidity, MIN_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECS);
        int refreshTokenValidity = uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getRefreshTokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe();
        refreshTokenValidity = Math.max(refreshTokenValidity, accessTokenValidity);
        /*
        For a better client design, this should be done by a ClientDetailsService (similar to UserDetailsService).
         */
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient(uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getClientId())
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getSecret()))
            .scopes("openid")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit","refresh_token", "password", "authorization_code")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValidity)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValidity)
            .and()
            .withClient(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getClientAuthorization().getClientId())
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getClientAuthorization().getClientSecret()))
            .scopes("web-app")
            .authorities("ROLE_GA")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds((int) jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getTokenValidityInSeconds())
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds((int) jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getTokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        //pick up all  TokenEnhancers incl. those defined in the application
        //this avoids changes to this class if an application wants to add its own to the chain
        Collection<TokenEnhancer> tokenEnhancers = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(TokenEnhancer.class).values();
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(new ArrayList<>(tokenEnhancers));
        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false);             //don't reuse or we will run into session inactivity timeouts
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    /**
     * Apply the token converter (and enhancer) for token store.
     * @return the {@link JwtTokenStore} managing the tokens.
     */
    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    /**
     * This bean generates an token enhancer, which manages the exchange between JWT access tokens and Authentication
     * in both directions.
     *
     * @return an access token converter configured with the authorization server's public/private keys.
     */
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
             new ClassPathResource(uaaProperties.getKeyStore().getName()), uaaProperties.getKeyStore().getPassword().toCharArray())
             .getKeyPair(uaaProperties.getKeyStore().getAlias());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                "isAuthenticated()");
    }
}
```

UAA Properties

```
uaa:
  key-store:
    name: config/tls/keystore.p12
    password: password
    alias: selfsigned
  web-client-configuration:
    # Access Token is valid for 5 mins
    access-token-validity-in-seconds: 300
    # Refresh Token is valid for 7 days
    refresh-token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 604800
    client-id: web_app
    secret: secret
```

Token Details

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

{
  "user_name": "username",
  "scope": [
    "openid"
  ],
  "exp": 1600274479,
  "iat": 1600274179,
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_MA",
    "ROLE_GA",
    "ROLE_XA"
  ],
  "jti": "9b607454-0241-437e-ac81-73f1f7b4f56a",
  "client_id": "web_app"
}
```

---

Token generation for the monolithic application is as follow

```java
@Component
public class TokenProvider implements InitializingBean {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenProvider.class);

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "auth";

    private Key key;

    private long tokenValidityInMilliseconds;

    private long tokenValidityInMillisecondsForRememberMe;

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    public TokenProvider(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes;
        String secret = jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getSecret();
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(secret)) {
            log.warn("Warning: the JWT key used is not Base64-encoded. " +
                "We recommend using the `jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.base64-secret` key for optimum security.");
            keyBytes = secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } else {
            log.debug("Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key");
            keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getBase64Secret());
        }
        this.key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
        this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds =
            1000 * jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getTokenValidityInSeconds();
        this.tokenValidityInMillisecondsForRememberMe =
            1000 * jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt()
                .getTokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe();
    }

    public String createToken(Authentication authentication, boolean rememberMe) {
        String authorities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        long now = (new Date()).getTime();
        Date validity;
        if (rememberMe) {
            validity = new Date(now + this.tokenValidityInMillisecondsForRememberMe);
        } else {
            validity = new Date(now + this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds);
        }

        return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(authentication.getName())
            .claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities)
            .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .setExpiration(validity)
            .compact();
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(key)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =
            Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        User principal = new User(claims.getSubject(), "", authorities);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, token, authorities);
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (io.jsonwebtoken.security.SecurityException | MalformedJwtException e) {
            log.info("Invalid JWT signature.");
            log.trace("Invalid JWT signature trace: {}", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            log.info("Expired JWT token.");
            log.trace("Expired JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            log.info("Unsupported JWT token.");
            log.trace("Unsupported JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.info("JWT token compact of handler are invalid.");
            log.trace("JWT token compact of handler are invalid trace: {}", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
  security:
    authentication:
      jwt:
        # This token must be encoded using Base64 and be at least 256 bits long (you can type `openssl rand -base64 64` on your command line to generate a 512 bits one)
        base64-secret: base64-secret-here
        # Token is valid 24 hours
        token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
        token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
```

```
{
  "alg": "HS512"
}

{
  "sub": "rvpatel",
  "auth": "ROLE_BC,ROLE_BE,ROLE_XE",
  "exp": 1602911681
}
```

**Question**

When I try to access the API which requires authentication from a monolithic application with the token generated in the authentication service I am getting the following exception

> Unsupported JWT token trace message: The parsed JWT indicates it was
> signed with the RS256 signature algorithm, but the specified signing
> key of type javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec may not be used to
> validate RS256 signatures.  Because the specified signing key reflects
> a specific and expected algorithm, and the JWT does not reflect this
> algorithm, it is likely that the JWT was not expected and therefore
> should not be trusted.  Another possibility is that the parser was
> configured with the incorrect signing key, but this cannot be assumed
> for security reasons.

As we can see from the token details algo is different for authentication service and monolithic application. I have changed the algo in TokenProvider to `SignatureAlgorithm.RS256` but it results in

> RSA signing keys must be PrivateKey instances.